# Waiting till user interaction stops before updating variable

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to fulfill the following user story.

1. A user uses zoom & pan on an interactive chart, zoom and panning several times a second until he find the data he's looking for.
2. After a pre-defined delay where there is no user interaction (i.e. two seconds after he's stopped zooming), his final min & max of the chart are pushed to a variable.
3. This step can be repeated several times, only updating the variable after a few seconds of 0 interactivity, not at every interaction.

The issue I need help with is creating a function in js that waits until 2 seconds after the final interaction before executing the update variable command.

Comment: Rough way: `setInterval`, clear it at every interaction, repeat.

Comment: some search terms for you: `throttle` and `debounce` are two types of functions that will allow you to control fast firing actions on a defined interval.  You are probably looking for `debounce`

Comment: Debounce was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks Davin. I found the following resource and it does exactly what I need. https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function